# Formula for Prime counting function for $n\leq 10^{14}$

Tags: number-theory

I've read about the prime counting function on wikipedia. All i found is a lot of mathematics(which i cannot decode) with different versions of formulas.
I wish to calculate number of prime numbers below a given $n$ that can be as large as $10^{14}$.
Is there any formula which can exactly compute the required result?
Help Please.

Comment: There is no formula but there is algorithm

Comment: Were you expecting a lot of dermatology?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you want to know the exact numbers, just use some existing program (several are even free).

Comment: @Thomas: I was expecting something which won't scare me by things out of my ken.

Comment: @quid: I was hoping to design something by myself. Though i could use them for subtasks. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a dream to have a nice closed formula for the prime-counting function $\pi(n)$.

We know that (it is the [PNT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)):
$$ \pi(n)\sim\frac{n}{\log n}$$
but a pretty deep math is involved in estimating $\pi(n)-\frac{n}{\log n}$.

By the way, $10^{14}$ is not really huge, you can find $\pi(N)$ with a [sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), for instance.

Comment: Could you provide me some reference(if available online) on using sieve?

Comment: There are closed formulas they are just so inconvenient that that dream is a night-mare.

Comment: @PranjalKatlana: have you had a look at the linked Wikipedia page?

Comment: @Jack : Yes i did. I found the answers i was seeking. Thanks :)